# PHP - Browser page source does not match what is displayed

Tags: php, security, caching, header

I have created a simple PHP script that can be used to password protect any other PHP file by simply including the file. I’ve encountered an issue that I’ve never witnessed before. Regardless of the web browser being used, what’s displayed on the page is entirely different from the HTML presented when you view the page source in the browser.

Here’s the scenario -- When you access a page secured by my script, you are presented a login form. The form has a checkbox. If you tick the box and login, you are then presented with a change password form. The page content that is being secured is not visible on the screen; only the change password form. However, the protected page content is what you see if you view the page source in the browser.

Simplified code example:

```
if ( $password_match ) {                    // If password matches DB...
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 3;               // ...log user in.
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = "user";
    $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();
    if ( pw_change_checkbox ) {             // If change password checkbox...
        print $change_password_template;    // ...present change password form.
    exit;
    }
// Show protected page content
}
```

Everything seems to be working as it should but why doesn’t the page source match what is displayed on the page? I did successfully login so is this a security concern? Is there a way to correct this? I have tried adding no-cache headers but it made no difference.

**UPDATE (2021-10-28 7:45 AM EST):**
Based on CBroe's comment, I think I better understand what's happening. I believe I'd have to change my code example above From:

```
if ( pw_change_checkbox ) {             // If change password checkbox...
    print $change_password_template;    // ...present change password form.
exit;
}
```

To something similar to this to make the page source match what is displayed on the screen:

```
if ( pw_change_checkbox ) {                  // If change password checkbox...
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/change-password.php'); //...redirect to change password form page.
exit;
}
```

Is my assessment correct?

Comment: If this only happens after they successfully login, what's the problem?

Comment: Please elaborate or show : "However, the protected page content is what you see if you view the page source in the browser." - give an example of protected page content being shown on the source....

Comment: Can't really tell from your "simplified" example, because there is just too much missing to show how it actually works; but my guess here is that the browser is making a new request when you click "show page source", and by that time your system will probably already consider the user to be logged in.

Comment: @Barmar - I guess this really isn't a problem but I thought it odd that the page source is totally different than what is displayed.

Comment: @Shlomtzion - I'm referring to right-clicking the page in the browser and selecting 'View Page Source'. If you do this, the HTML that you see is the exact same as if you logged in without ticking the password change checkbox. The page source should be that of the password change form but it is not even though the password change form is displayed on the screen.

Comment: @CBroe - My script is actually comprised of several different files i.e., config, function and other includes. That's why I posted only a snippet of how the password change form is presented to the user. I think your assessment is on target but I'm still fuzzy on exactly what is happening.

Comment: How are you validating your form? also , how it is structured? you can let the form post run and then the reload page will remove the data. If you are validating through ajax you need to define the form elements correctly. Or if the wrong form is dispalyed in the source its because one is from php/html and the 2nd is JS? can you show your code?

Comment: @Shlomtzion - The form is validated client-side and server-side. I get the same results even when I disable client-side validation. The login form is posted to itself so the page is refreshed. I edited my original post. Please read my update and see if you concur with CBroe’s and my assessments.